# Autocomplete using spaces

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

I needed your help with the following code. In this code I am implementing autocomplete in an input box using javascript, but it is not working after using space inside the input box. I.e.: If I type "harsh friend" then it's not working for the word "friend".

```js
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  var currentFocus;
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() ==            
val.toUpperCase()) {

          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
           b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
   inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        currentFocus++;
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
        currentFocus--;
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
   function addActive(x) {
    if (!x) return false;
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
      x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {

    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
          closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}

var countries = ["harsh","ayush","bombay","cat","gre","killing","friend"];


autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 16px Arial;  
}


.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[type=text] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
}

.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  background-color: #e9e9e9; 
}

.autocomplete-active {
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important; 
  color: #ffffff; 
}
```

```html
<h2>Autocomplete</h2>

<p>Start typing:</p>


<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes in your code.
Basically I changed the way your were searching from first letter of each array item to **all** letters in each array item. For that I used the e.data to make the search.

```
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
    var currentFocus;
    inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
        var a, b, i, val = this.value, sentence;
        closeAllLists();
        if (!val) {
            return false;
        }
        currentFocus = -1;
        a = document.createElement("DIV");
        a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
        this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
            if (arr[i].toUpperCase().includes(e.data.toUpperCase())) {
                render(e.data);
            }
        }
        function render(letter) {
            b = document.createElement("DIV");
            b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
            b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
            b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
            b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                sentence = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value.slice(0, -1);
                inp.value = sentence;
                inp.value += this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                closeAllLists();
            });
            a.appendChild(b);
        }
    });
    //
    inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
        if (e.keyCode == 40) { // down arrow
            currentFocus++;
            addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { // up arrow
            currentFocus--;
            addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 13) { // enter
            e.preventDefault();
            if (currentFocus > -1) {
                if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
            }
        }
    });
    //
    function addActive(x) {
        if (!x) return false;
        removeActive(x);
        if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
        if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
        x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
    }
    function removeActive(x) {
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
        }
    }
    function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
                x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        closeAllLists(e.target);
    });
}
//
var countries = ["harsh","ayush","bombay","cat","gre","killing","friend", "Sri Lanka"];
//
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
```